# c++ Pointers and Memory Leaks - The Answer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

I already coded in PHP, SQL, Javascript, Java, C#, Delphi. I'm not an expert but I can achieve great things. Now, I'm learning C++ from the beginning because I think as a low level language it could be very interesting to understand closer hardware stuff such as pointers.

I have read a lot here and on google about the pointers. I understand them it's not that hard to understand as many people say. I think if you understand references you should understand pointers.

However, it's not clear on a point, Memory leaks. In fact I think it is BUT many answers from forum and even here are contradicting each others. I have read about pointers but I didn't tried them because of this famous question:

Is memory leaks can lead in a faulty memory for my computer (OS X), and this forever? I mean a chunk of memory are stuck forever.

On forums some say if you don't free/delete pointers to free the memory it will remain stuck forever, **but** many say an interesting point which say that once you close your application, your OS will free all the application's memory.

So what's the good answer? Because I would like to play with it to learn more on that but I don't want to fill forever some chunks of my memory cause problems to it.

Comment: If leaked memory was "stuck forever" you'd have to buy new RAM every other day...

Comment: Your OS will take care of it after your program is closed. However, if you have memory leaks you can run out of memory during the execution of your program.

Comment: If you really made Delphi code (not only clicking compoennts) - memory model is almost the same. rest of your question is totally of topic "memory lost forever"

Comment: BTW get knowledge from good books, not from forums

Comment: You shouldn't worry about *pointers*. You should worry about manual memory allocation.

Comment: @Mat Yes it was my concern. Make no sense to me but I had to get an answer and move on. Thanks

Comment: @apalomer Yes exactly what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: @JacekCz Delphi was in my very very very first day of programming, during the mIRC script coding in the 90's :) I didn't learned memory allocation and either pointers at this time. Currently i'm using 3 websites to learn. Openclassrooms, cplusplus and an other. For each steps, I read the same steps on other websites. Many informations are complemantary.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes it's the next step alloc. But why?

Comment: Would like to thanks everybody that Voted me down. Maybe for some of you this is a stupid question but for me it was important. I had read a lot on that but I had not found clear answers. Now i'm sure about what is it and I totally understand.

TRUE thanks to people who answered me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a memory leak will not break your computer forever.  What it can do is make your application claim RAM that it isn't using anymore, which could eventually cause this or another program to crash when they need more memory and there isn't any left.  But as soon as the program with the leak is exited or killed the memory will be reclaimed by the OS and available to any program again.

Even if the OS has a bug and didn't reclaim it, worst case a reboot would fix the problem.  So you have no need to worry about hurting your computer by trying things out, the worst that can happen is an app will crash.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, but I just wanted to be sure as the C++ is a low level language.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason so much emphasis is given on memory leaks in languages like C/C++ is because there is no such thing called as garbage collector which can automatically free the memory allocated on heap when no further references are found to exist.

If you leak a memory, for instance below code (although it doesn't solves any purpose), the 100 bytes below won't be freed.

```
void doTest() {
char *mem =new char[100];
return;
}
```

If this function is called several times, the heap memory of your app will keep on increasing which may eventually slow down the application and the system. Also, further requests for memory may fail, creating functional failures in the application.

Be assured, once you close the application this memory will be freed and reclaimed the by system, however till your application is running that chunk of the heap won't be available for use.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, put it short and somewhat oversimplified, in C++ you can create your objects on stack. In this case you don't have to worry about returning memory back. On leaving given scope, destructor for your object will be called automagically and that's all.

Creating objects on stack is fast and easy, however, stack memory is limited, besides, you may want to pass your object around between subroutines. This is where you need heap memory. By calling `new` you request a memory block to hold data for your object. You get a pointer to created object and you can pass it around. However, heap memory is not infinite resource, too. From time to time you need to return memory back, when you don't need it anymore.

Failure to do so may result in situation where you eventually find yourself running out of memory. Every subsequent call to `new` will result in `bad_alloc` exception and no new objects will be created. This is definitely not what you want. Hence, every `new` needs a symmetrical call to `delete` to ensure you won't end up starving for heap memory.

No physical harm to your RAM will be incurred by memory leaks in any way.

Comment: You don't need to call `new` to pass things between "subroutines".

Comment: @juanchopanza, right, but why do you think I mentioned, that this is somewhat oversimplified picture?

Comment: It is a nonsense picture.

Comment: How about `move`-semantics? Should I go into gory details of it here? Or still nonsense?

Comment: No, you should simply abstain from saying nonsense.

Comment: Why should I? They aren't spouting nonsense.

Comment: How do you interact with legacy/C-code? Have you ever worked with Qt? What about initializing smart pointers with `new`'d values? Still nonsense? And, finally, have you really read the linked answer? I'm afraid, the only nonsense is in your head.

Comment: Yes. Yes. What about it? I remind you of my first comment: "You don't need to call new to pass things between "subroutines"."

Comment: I know, "manual mm" should be avoided because of dangers it entails, I know about references in C++ and passing by value, especially with advent of `move` in C++11. I know there're ways to obtain pointers without using `new`, but there are cases when you still have to get your hands dirty anyways. After all, usage of `new` even wasn't the main point of the answer. Only the most obvious example how one might run into problems. OTOH, all your arguing is - "nonsense". Maybe try other arguments? I'm really tired of this pointless discussion. Sry.